Ubuntu 24.04 LTS - XRDP - Plug in a dongle to use Bluetooth
I installed Ubuntu 24.04 LTS on LattePanda 3 Delta.
In the beginning, I faced a strange problem - when I activated Desktop Sharing and after Remote Login, I couldn't back to Desktop Sharing. I tried it a few times with a fresh Ubuntu installation. However, the Remote Login function was pretty slow - I used Windows 11 to connect with the Ubuntu machine. For me it was not understandable because it's a native function of Ubuntu.
In the end, I have installed xRDP using this tutorial: https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=19671
Now it works better but I am faced with a next problem. On a physical device, my Bluetooth works and everything works correctly. During the xRDP session, I don't have access to Bluetooth. In settings, I see the information: Plug in a dongle to use Bluetooth. I'm connecting to the Ubuntu machine as the same user (only one user has been added).
I checked Google and I found this post: Cannot unblock soft-blocked bluetooth
Bluetooth was locked by soft and I ran every command but without result.
In the end, I have installed Blueman using this solution: No Bluetooth Found. Plug in a dongle to use bluetooth
Finally, something has changed and I could connect headphones or a smartphone. I can send files from and to the Ubuntu machine using Bluetooth. But I can't for example change the output of sound. I have only xrdp and dummy output.
So my final questions are:

Do I correctly set an XRDP connection using the tutorial above? Ubuntu solutions didn't work for me correctly.
Has anybody faced the same issue with Bluetooth?
I am connecting to user A locally. I'm connecting to user A via XRDP. Should I add this user to the audio and Bluetooth etc. group to use these functions remotely? How can I do this?

Thank you for every advice.
Best regards

I found a solution to my problem. I just added my user (the only user in Ubuntu) to every group in the system. I don't know which group was the most important but it works.
I uninstalled Blueman and see Bluetooth devices directly in the Ubuntu menu/settings.
Now I have another issue. I can connect via XRDP with my Bluetooth headphones but can't set them as an audio output.
I have only xrdp audio and built-in speakers.
Has anybody any solution for it?

If you have a new question, ask it separately using the Ask Question button.
